# Implement a query based on parent ID relationships

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a simple table that requires a semi-complex retrieval of information.  The table is:

### TABLE - posts

```
id        - bigint(20)
title     - varchar(250)
content   - longtext
parent_id - int(20)
type      - varchar(50)
```

Currently, I have three different values for type that go into the posts table - group, discussion, and reply.  The data is stored in such a way that:

1. A reply has a discussion id as its parent_id.
2. A discussion has a group id (or 0) as its parent_id.

Members of the site can join a group and I want to include the discussions and replies from that group in their email digest.  Currently, I am using LEFT JOINS to accomplish this, but it becomes heavy because I have to have a lot of joins to accomplish it and performance is digressing as the table grows quickly.

Does anyone have any suggestions for a better implementation?  I have looked into the nested set model, but I don't believe it will help me here because the retrieval is based on an action on the top-level group entry, so the data retrieved needs to be tied to it.

Thoughts and responses greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about each having its own table? i.e. Groups, Discussions, Posts?

Comment: Seeing as MySQL doesn't support CTE, nested set model would be your best bet.
Other than that, I highly suggest changing your model to use different tables for what are in fact different types of objects..

Answer (score 1):

If your data model is replies are in discussions are in groups, then you should have three different tables for these entities.  This gives more information to the SQL engine for optimizing the queries.

It may be too late for that.  In that case, you need to be sure that you have appropriate indexes.  For instance, to get all discussions in a group, there is a query like this:

```
select *
from posts p
where p.parent_id = XXX and p.type = 'Discussion'
```

This suggests that you need an index on `type`, probably posts(type, id).  To see what other indexes might be useful, you would need to modify your question to include some of the queries you are using.